# AngularJS : Keep view state between differents views with differents controllers

Tags: javascript, angularjs, routes, angular-ui-router

My angular application starts on a /home state ( i use ui-router ), which have its own controller, in which i call a factory method to get some json objects from my API that i share thanks to this factory between the whole app. I put the list that i get from this in a $scope object of the /home state.

What i want to do is to call this init method of the factory only once, even better would be that the /home controller is only called once.

Actually when i go to another state like /about, and when i go back to /home, the /home controller is called again and so is the init method of the factory. So how do i keep the initial view state ?

**StuffFactory.js :**

```
app.factory('StuffFactory', function ($window, $http, $q) {

var stuffs;

return {
    initStuffsList: function () {

        return $http.get('http://myapi/stuff/init')
                .then(function (response) {

                    stuffs = (angular.fromJson(response.data.result));

                });


    },
    getStuffs: function () {
        return stuffs;
    }

};
```

});

**homeController.js :**

```
app.controller('homeCtrl', function ($scope,StuffFactory) {


StuffFactory.initStuffsList().then(function(){
         $scope.stuffs = StuffFactory.getStuffs();

       });

});
```

**app.js :**

```
        .config(['$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider']


            $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/home');

            $stateProvider


                    .state('home', {
                        url: '/home',
                        templateUrl: './partials/home.html',
                        controller:homeCtrl
                        })
                        .state('about', {
                            url: '/about',
                            templateUrl: './partials/about.html',
                            controller:aboutCtrl
                        })
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The factory is a singleton, so you can do the one-off initialisation in the factory and simply return a promise from `initStuffsList`. Now the initialisation only happens once but your controller can still be sure it happens at least once.

```
app.factory('StuffFactory', function ($window, $http, $q) {

    var stuffs;
    var initialised = $http.get('http://myapi/stuff/init')
        .then(function (response) {
             return stuffs = (angular.fromJson(response.data.result));
         });
    return {
        initStuffsList: function () {
            return initialised;
        },
        getStuffs: function () {
            return stuffs;
        }
    };
});
```

The controller remains unchanged:

```
app.controller('homeCtrl', function ($scope,StuffFactory) {

StuffFactory.initStuffsList().then(function(){
         $scope.stuffs = StuffFactory.getStuffs();

       });
});
```

Note also that you can return the value from the initialisation code directly to the controller, so with the `return` I inserted above this will also work:

```
app.controller('homeCtrl', function ($scope,StuffFactory) {

StuffFactory.initStuffsList().then(function(stuffs){
         $scope.stuffs = stuffs;
       });
});
```

Comment: Thank you really much ! This is exactly what I tried to do without knowing how.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

Service:

```
app.factory('StuffFactory', function ($http, $q) {

  var _stuffs; // cache stuffs

  return {
    getStuffs: function () {
      if (_stuffs) {
        return $q.when(_stuffs);
      }
      return $http.get('http://myapi/stuff/init').then(function (response) {
        _stuffs = (angular.fromJson(response.data.result));
        return _stuffs;
      });
    }
  };
});
```

Controller A and B:

```
StuffFactory.getStuffs().then(function(stuffs){
  $scope.stuffs = stuffs;
});
```

The second time you will call the method `getStuffs()` you will get the data from the cache.

Answer (score 0):

One simple solution would be one additional wrapping state:

```
.state('home', {
    template: '<ui-view></ui-view>',
    controller: homeCtrl,
    abstract: true
})
.state('home.index', {
    templateUrl: './partials/home.html'
})
.state('home.about', {
    templateUrl: './partials/about.html',
    controller: aboutCtrl
})
```

This way `home` is the parent state of both states and its controller will only be loaded once and stay active as long as you're in any `home.` state.

Comment: My question here is willingly simplified : I really need to have separated controllers for those two views which are more complex than just home/about :)

Comment: You can still have individual controllers. `home` here has one controller which will persist across both states. `home.index` and `home.about` can have their individual controllers which will be specific to that view (`home.about` demonstrates this here in fact). Just move every shared piece into `homeCtrl` and all state-specific code into state-specific controllers.